# Customize ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, abpersonviewcontroller

Is it possible to add custom UITableViewCell row in addition to built-in email, phone rows inside ABPersonViewController? 
I would like to add buttons like add, remove, etc in that cell, which will allow user to be added/removed into/from my application. 
Please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you've gotten the answer to this by this point, but I was just looking into do this myself.

Basically, No.

These controllers are not designed to be customized and Apple mentions it in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3507849/819355

It subclasses `ABPersonViewController` which allows you to play a bit with the screen controls...